# Como resolver las columnas de un formulario de contacto

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un formulario de contacto el cual quiero que los  `div`  de la class col-md-6 col-sm-4 se posicionen en forma horizontal y no en forma vertical abajo del otro.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
         
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <form action="#" method="get"  data-wow-delay="0.6s">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="ENVIAR">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Ya que colocaste en un snippet tu código, no olvides agregar bootstrap como librería externa. Además: _las columnas siempre dentro de filas_ :)

Comment: Ya tengo la librería de bootstrap agregado y están dentro del row  nomas que solo saque esa parte del código.

Comment: Bootstrap no está como librería en el snippet, es por eso que se ve como HTML plano. Recuerda agregar un [repro].

Comment: Ya inserte la librería

Comment: al form ponle class="row"

Comment: te faltaría un row, para que no tome las metricas del row externo al form. podes ponerle la class row al form o un div.row dentro del form ( asi los anchos de cols de los input son relativos a ese row y no el externo q es un col 6)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ya quedo.

Comment: Recuerda siempre que la estructura de grilla de Bootstrap es filas > columnas. Si solo agregas columnas (que no están dentro de filas), tendrás "estructuras inesperadas".

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo la documentación de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Removí la etiqueta `<div class="row">` y agregue la clase *row* directamente en tu etiqueta `<form>`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="contact">
      <div class="container">
             
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <form class="row" action="#" method="get"  data-wow-delay="0.6s">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="ENVIAR">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Ojo que quedaron columnas sin fila: el form tiene un row, pero su padre (el div) tiene columnas, y no están dentro de otra fila.

Comment: Entonces entendí mal la pregunta, creí que quería las columnas de **Name** y **Email** las quería en horizontal.

Comment: el form está dentro de un col-6 de un row, salvo que eso lo quiera quitar y "agrandar" el form no haría falta remover ese row, sino sólo agregar el row interno

Comment: @aloMalbarez Hmmm, ¿interno o externo?

Comment: el externo da el ancho al form, col6 es un 50% debe ser para que quede cuadradito al centro, el interno es el que marca la grilla de los input